# Can't get class to be trivially copyable. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++

I trying to make the following class "trivially copyable".  I don't seem to be getting this.  I've followed all [trivially copyable requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable) but I keep getting 'false' when testing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstring>

template<typename T>
struct mytype
{
    T * data;


    mytype() noexcept
    { 
        data = nullptr;
    }

    mytype(const mytype<T> &other) 
    {
        std::memmove(&data,&other.data,sizeof(data));
    }

    mytype(const mytype<T> &&other)
    {
        data = std::move(other.data);
    }



    mytype<T>& operator= (const mytype<T> other)
    {
        std::memmove(&data,&other.data,sizeof(data));
    }

    mytype<T>& operator= (const mytype<T> && other)
    {
        data = std::move(other.data);
    }

    ~mytype ()
    {

    }

};


int main ()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_trivially_copyable<mytype<int>>::value << '\n'; //returns "false"
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone offer a suggestion?

Comment: You can't get a trivially copyable type with a pointer in it that points to dynamically allocated memroy.

Comment: "I've followed all trivially copyable requirements" - as far as I can see, you have violated every single one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Trivial_copy_constructor:

> The copy constructor for class T is trivial if all of the following
>   are true:
>
> - it is not user-provided (that is, it is implicitly-defined or defaulted) , and if it is defaulted, its signature is the same as
>     implicitly-defined (until C++14)

You must not define any of those (copy|move)-constructors, destructors and assignment operators, otherwise they are just not any longer trivial.

Comment: std::atomic requires a trivially copyable type.  However to use std::atomic::store it requires a copy constructor to be implemented because by default the copy constructor is marked as 'delete'.  I wanted to ask about this but the site won't let me b/c some stackoverflow snobs/nazis downvoted me.